# how to call a method in startActivityForResult in android using kotlin?

Tags: android, react-native, android-pay, react-native-native-module, native-module

I'm writing a *native module* in order to **adding a generic pass to google wallet** in *React Native* using kotlin. according to google wallet api documentation for android (https://developers.google.com/wallet/generic/android), I have to implement a onActivityResult function to get the result after user tap on the add to google wallet button.

According to React Native documentation about how to listen to a `onActivityResult` (https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.71/native-modules-android?android-language=kotlin#getting-activity-result-from-startactivityforresult) I'm trying to call `walletClient.savePassesJwt(jwtSignedToken, this, addToGoogleWalletRequestCode)` method to get it's result on `onActivityResult` function. I don't know what Intent to use for this matter and i get the followin error in *JavaScript* side of my **React Native** project.

```
{"info": "{
  \"nativeStackAndroid\": [
    {
      \"lineNumber\": 2174,
      \"file\": \"Instrumentation.java\",
      \"methodName\": \"checkStartActivityResult\",
      \"class\": \"android.app.Instrumentation\"
    },
    {
      \"lineNumber\": 1805,
      \"file\": \"Instrumentation.java\",
      \"methodName\": \"execStartActivity\",
      \"class\": \"android.app.Instrumentation\"
    },
    {
      \"lineNumber\": 5596,
      \"file\": \"Activity.java\",
      \"methodName\": \"startActivityForResult\",
      \"class\": \"android.app.Activity\"
    },
    {
      \"lineNumber\": 597,
      \"file\": \"ComponentActivity.java\",
      \"methodName\": \"startActivityForResult\",
      \"class\": \"androidx.activity.ComponentActivity\"
    },
    {
      \"lineNumber\": 5554,
      \"file\": \"Activity.java\",
      \"methodName\": \"startActivityForResult\",
      \"class\": \"android.app.Activity\"
    },
    {
      \"lineNumber\": 583,
      \"file\": \"ComponentActivity.java\",
      \"methodName\": \"startActivityForResult\",
      \"class\": \"androidx.activity.ComponentActivity\"
    },
    {
      \"lineNumber\": 112,
      \"file\": \"GoogleWalletModule.kt\",
      \"methodName\": \"savePassToGoogleWallet\",
      \"class\": \"com.peaktowertech.digivcard.GoogleWalletModule\"
    },
    {
      \"lineNumber\": -2,
      \"file\": \"Method.java\",
      \"methodName\": \"invoke\",
      \"class\": \"java.lang.reflect.Method\"
    },
    {
      \"lineNumber\": 372,
      \"file\": \"JavaMethodWrapper.java\",
      \"methodName\": \"invoke\",
      \"class\": \"com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper\"
    },
    {
      \"lineNumber\": 188,
      \"file\": \"JavaModuleWrapper.java\",
      \"methodName\": \"invoke\",
      \"class\": \"com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper\"
    },
    {
      \"lineNumber\": -2,
      \"file\": \"NativeRunnable.java\",
      \"methodName\": \"run\",
      \"class\": \"com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable\"
    },
    {
      \"lineNumber\": 942,
      \"file\": \"Handler.java\",
      \"methodName\": \"handleCallback\",
      \"class\": \"android.os.Handler\"
    },
    {
      \"lineNumber\": 99,
      \"file\": \"Handler.java\",
      \"methodName\": \"dispatchMessage\",
      \"class\": \"android.os.Handler\"
    },
    {
      \"lineNumber\": 27,
      \"file\": \"MessageQueueThreadHandler.java\",
      \"methodName\": \"dispatchMessage\",
      \"class\": \"com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler\"
    },
    {
      \"lineNumber\": 226,
      \"file\": \"Looper.java\",
      \"methodName\": \"loopOnce\",
      \"class\": \"android.os.Looper\"
    },
    {
      \"lineNumber\": 313,
      \"file\": \"Looper.java\",
      \"methodName\": \"loop\",
      \"class\": \"android.os.Looper\"
    },
    {
      \"lineNumber\": 228,
      \"file\": \"MessageQueueThreadImpl.java\",
      \"methodName\": \"run\",
      \"class\": \"com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4\"
    },
    {
      \"lineNumber\": 1012,
      \"file\": \"Thread.java\",
      \"methodName\": \"run\",
      \"class\": \"java.lang.Thread\"
    }
  ],
  \"userInfo\": null,
  \"message\": \"No Activity found to handle Intent {  }\",
  \"code\": \"E_FAILED_TO_SHOW_WALLET_FLOW\"
}", "message": "Add to google wallet failed"}
```

My native kotlin module:

```
package com.example.something;
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseActivityEventListener
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback
import com.facebook.react.bridge.LifecycleEventListener
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod
import com.google.android.gms.pay.Pay
import com.google.android.gms.pay.PayClient
import com.google.android.gms.pay.PayApiAvailabilityStatus

class GoogleWalletModule(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext, private var walletClient: PayClient=Pay.getClient(reactContext)) : ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {


    private val addToGoogleWalletRequestCode = 1000

    private var saveToWalletPromise: Promise? = null

    private val activityEventListener =
        object : BaseActivityEventListener() {
            override fun onActivityResult(
                activity: Activity?,
                requestCode: Int,
                resultCode: Int,
                data: Intent?
            ) {
                if (requestCode == addToGoogleWalletRequestCode) {

                    saveToWalletPromise?.let { promise ->

                        when (resultCode) {
                            Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                                // Pass saved successfully
                            }

                            Activity.RESULT_CANCELED -> {
                                // Save operation canceled
                                promise.reject(E_ADD_TO_WALLET_CANCELLED, "Add to wallet was cancelled")
                            }

                            PayClient.SavePassesResult.SAVE_ERROR -> data?.let { intentData ->
                                val errorMessage =
                                    intentData.getStringExtra(PayClient.EXTRA_API_ERROR_MESSAGE)
                                // Handle error
                                promise.reject(E_FAILED_TO_SAVE_PASS,errorMessage)
                            }

                            else -> {
                                // Handle unexpected (non-API) exception
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    init {
        reactContext.addActivityEventListener(activityEventListener)
    }


    override fun getName() = "GoogleWalletModule"

    @ReactMethod fun isGoogleWalletApiAvailable(myFailureCallback: Callback, mySuccessCallback: Callback) {
        walletClient
            .getPayApiAvailabilityStatus(PayClient.RequestType.SAVE_PASSES)
            .addOnSuccessListener { status ->
                if (status == PayApiAvailabilityStatus.AVAILABLE) {
                    // The API is available, show the button in your UI
                    mySuccessCallback.invoke(true)
                } else {
                    // The user or device is not eligible for using the Pay API
                    mySuccessCallback.invoke(false)
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                // Hide the button and optionally show an error message
                myFailureCallback.invoke("E_WRONG")
            }
    }


    @ReactMethod fun savePassToGoogleWallet(jwtSignedToken: String,promise: Promise) {
        val activity = currentActivity

        if (activity == null) {
            promise.reject(E_ACTIVITY_DOES_NOT_EXIST, "Activity doesn't exist")
            return
        }

        saveToWalletPromise = promise

        try {

            val igniterIntent = Intent().apply {
                () -> walletClient.savePassesJwt(jwtSignedToken, activity, addToGoogleWalletRequestCode)
            }

            activity.startActivityForResult(igniterIntent,addToGoogleWalletRequestCode)
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            saveToWalletPromise?.reject(E_FAILED_TO_SHOW_ADD_TO_WALLET, t)
            saveToWalletPromise = null
        }

    }


    companion object {
        const val E_ACTIVITY_DOES_NOT_EXIST = "E_ACTIVITY_DOES_NOT_EXIST"
        const val E_ADD_TO_WALLET_CANCELLED = "E_PICKER_CANCELLED"
        const val E_FAILED_TO_SHOW_ADD_TO_WALLET = "E_FAILED_TO_SHOW_WALLET_FLOW"
        const val E_FAILED_TO_SAVE_PASS = "E_FAILED_TO_SAVE_PASS"
    }

}
```

I am not familiar with android development. Could anyone help me how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

- Pre-requistic

  - `GoogleWalletModule` is added into React Package
  - React Package is added into `MainApplication.kt` (your Main class under `android/src/main/java/com/example/something`)
- For `startActivityForResult` to give result in the listener event. You would need to send the result back.

  - Within your function `savePassesJwt(..)` send the result by calling below functions for success and failure case

    - Success case

      - `activity.sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, addToGoogleWalletRequestCode)`
    - Failure or cancel case

      - `activity.sendResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, addToGoogleWalletRequestCode)`
  - Passing `addToGoogleWalletRequestCode` within `sendResult(..)` will help map the correct requester.

Further Read: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: Thanks man. The startActivityForResult method takes two parameter, the first one is an Intent and I don't know what intent should I use here to call savePassesJwt in it!

Comment: is `walletClient.savePassesJwt` is some external page or internal logic to save jwt token. You don't need to call startActivityForResult if its not invoking any activity or fragment it can be simple threading logic with callbacks

Comment: Actually, walletClient.savePassesJwt() opens google wallet app which I think is an activity but I don't know what kind of intent it is!